# Java Hibernate map list of list of entities @AssociationOverrides

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

Hi I have 3 entities.

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    ...

    private List<BC> bcList;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    ...

}

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

These entities are linked by ManyToMany associations each other. It means I need an association table which look like a_b_c(**id_a,id_b,id_c**). 
So I've created an AssociationOverrides which work exactly as I want.

```
@Embeddable
public class ABCPK implements Serializable {


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_a")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_b")
    private B b;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_c")
    private C c;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "a_b_c")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.a",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_a",referencedColumnName = "id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.b",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_b",referencedColumnName = "id")) ,
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.c",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_c",referencedColumnName = "id")) })
public class ABC{

    @EmbeddedId
    private ABCPK pk=new ABCPK();

    @Transient
    public A getA() {
        return pk.getA();
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.pk.setA(a);
    }
    ...


}

public class BC{
    private B b;
    private List<C> cList;
}
```

However I would like to retrieve List bcList and List cList from my association table but I really don't know how can I do it. I've already tried @JoinFormula but I prefere to get it working using jpql only. Could you please put me in the right way ?
Thanks

Comment: If I replace the List<BC> bcList by HashMap<B, List<C> bcMap does anyone know how I could populate this Hashmap using Annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't got any help I've made up my mind to populate my map myself and re populate abcList before persist and update . However I really don't like this since it's not performance and memory friendly. (about 1*20*70 items in the abcList)

```
@Entity
public class A {
  ...
    @OneToMany
    private List<ABC> abcList;
    private Map<B,List<C>> bcMap;

    private Map<B,List<C>> buildBCmap(){
        bcMap  = new HashMap<>();
        if(abcList!=null){
            for(ABC abc:abcList){
                if(! bcMap.containsKey(abc.getB()){
                    bcMap.put(abc.getB(),new ArrayList<>());
                }   
                bcMap.get(abc.getB()).add(abc.getC());
            }
        }
        return bcMap;
    }

    public Map<B,List<C>> getBcMap(){
        if(bcMap==null){
            buildBCmap();
        }
        return bcMap;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void buildAbcList(){
        if(bcMap!=null){
            abcList=new ArrayList<>();
            for(B b: bcMap.keySet()){
                for(C c: bcMap.get(b)){
                    abcList.add(new ABC(this,b,c));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have a better or faster way to populate a map from associationOverride entity ?